# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property _currentElement of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-native, jsx

I have an input that i'm trying to format/mask as a currency. I'm using a package to accomplish this (CurrencyInput). I keep getting this error on my component `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property _currentElement of null` and I don't understand why. If I use React's TextInput it works correctly. I've tried 10 different packages from NPM and I keep getting the same error. How can I find out what's causing this?

I've checked responses of similar issues posted.... The answers I've seen don't seem apply to my situation.  My components are loaded before mounting, no undefined props (from what I can see) and I'm on a stable version of React.

```
class Profile extends React.PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    handleLogout: PropTypes.func,
    handleaciNav: PropTypes.func,
    user: PropTypes.object
  };

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerVisible: true,
    title: 'Profile'
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onCreditCardChange = this
      .onCreditCardChange
      .bind(this);
    this.onCreditCardFocus = this
      .onCreditCardFocus
      .bind(this);

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }


  getInitialState(){
        return ({amount: "0.00"});
    }

 handleChange(event, maskedvalue, floatvalue){
        this.setState({amount: maskedvalue});
    }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("www.some.com", {method: 'get'})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({data: data});

      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        //
      })

  }


  callBoth = () => {

    console.log(this.state.data)
  }

  render() {

    if (this.state.data.length === 0) {
      return null

    }

    return (
      <ContentWrapper>

        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            {jsonData}
            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor='transparent'
              style={styles.btn}
              onPress={this.goToAcibtnTwo}>
              <Image source={images.prredbtn}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Text style={styles.textthingsmall}>{'Must be Paid Immediately'}</Text>

            {jsonData2}
            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor='transparent'
              style={styles.btn}
              onPress={this.goToAcibtnTwo}>
              <Image source={images.prgreenbtn}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Text style={styles.textthingsmall}>{'May include next payment or other fees'}</Text>

            {jsonData3}
            <TouchableHighlight
              underlayColor='transparent'
              style={styles.btn}
              onPress={this.goToAcibtnTwo}>
              <Image source={images.prgreenbtn}></Image>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            {jsonData4}
            <View>

            <CurrencyInput value={this.state.amount} onChangeEvent={this.handleChange}/>
            </View>

          </View>
          <View>
            <Image style={styles.btmicons} source={images.optionsroundbtn}/>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ContentWrapper>

    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: There are number of questions with this same error. You can see them in the "Related" section to the right. Can you please explain why none of those answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I've checked multiple instances of the questions posted.... The answers I've seen don't seem apply to my situation.  My components are loaded before mounting, no undefined props (from what I can see) and I'm on a stable version of React.

Comment: That's information that should be in the question. Feel free to [edit] your question and add that information so that others know it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Will do. Thanks!

Comment: what package are you using? if it has anything regarding dom/html/css it will not work with react-native

Comment: Why are you using `React.PureComponent` instead of `React.Component`?

Comment: I used PureComponent to enhance performance